# Replace multiple strings between two char

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
str = “Here are \*\*text1\*\* and \*\*text2\*\* replace those **texts.”

console.log(str.replace(/\*\*.*\*\*/, ‘replaced’)); // Here are replaced texts.
```

It should display `“Here are replaced and replaced replace those **texts.”`

Note - It should handle dynamic strings between ** not just for text1 and text2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `*` and use `?` for non-greedy matching after `.*`:

```js
const func = str => str.replace(/\*\*.*?\*\*/g, 'replaced');

console.log(func('Here are **text1** and **text2** replace those **texts.'));
console.log(func('Here is **some longer text** **'));
```